# Hightlight Gridview Rows On Mouseover

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have to highlight a cell of a gridview on mouseover. Got a problem in highlight. I am checking if the cell has  it will highlight.

// Source

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gvrecords tr:td').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlightRow');
    });
    $('#gvrecords tr').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('highlightRow');
    })
    })
    </script>
```

Where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A smal trick wil do this.

```
$('#gvrecords tr:has(td)').mouseover(function()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have chose wrong selector, :td is not correct. You need to attach event directly on tr. You may  use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` as mouseover will fire again and again as mouse moves on it, `it will cause needless execution of code`. You need to change the class only once so mouse enter would be do that for you.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Bf3MT/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gvrecords tr').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).addClass('highlightRow');
    }).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('highlightRow');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS, which may work out easier:

```
#gvrecords tr {
     background-color: #FFF;
}

#gvrecords tr:hover {
     background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `css`

```
.highlightRow
{
  background-color:your_color;
}
```